# Write using only the logical operators and symbols $ +, *, 1, 0, \le, |$ : "x is the greatest common factor of a and b"

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Write using only the logical operators and symbols $ +, *, 1, 0, \le, |$ : "x is the greatest common factor of a and b" 
To begin with, I came up with a definition of the greatest common factor: $$GCF(x, y) = \max \{z: z|x \land z| y \}$$
And so I tried to copy this definition using only the allowed symbols: 
$$x|a \land x|b \land  1\le x $$ But this notation does not guarantee that x is the biggest number with this property, and so there will be more than one number satisfying this formula. What should I change to make it work?

Comment: Remember [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). That's all they want you to do.

Comment: So should it be 
$am + bn = x$?

Comment: It is not quite clear what we are allowed to use. Are we allowed to use additional letters , and can we assume that they are integers ?

Comment: "But this notation does not guarantee that x is the biggest number with this property"  So ... say it is.  $... \land (y|a\land y|b \implies y \le x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we can just be literal.

Greatest common factor of $a$ and $b$ means

$x$ so that $a|x$ and $b|x$ and if $y > x$ then  $y$ is not a common multiple or

$x$ so that $a|x$ and $b|x$ and if $y$ is a common multiple then $y \le x$.  So

$x: x|a \land x|b \land [(y|a \land y|b) \implies y \le x)]$.